# Query to find Children over 10 years of age

Tags: sql-server

I have a project where I had to create a Church Database. After its creation I have to make a SQL query to find all single parents with Children under the age of 10

I have a marital status column in the Members table which I used to find the single parents, of which there are two. But as soon as I remove it the age check doesn't work. Below is the single parent check.

```
  --inner join Children c on c.Father_Id = p.Member_Id 
  --or c.Mother_Id = p.Member_Id

select p.[First Name] 
from Members p, Children c
where p.[Marital Status] = 1 and (GETDATE() - c.Birthday) > 10
```

Im expecting to get only the two parents to be listed.

Edit 1.Full Query:

`select distinct p.[First Name]
from Members p
  inner join Children c on c.Father_Id = p.Member_Id
  or c.Mother_Id = p.Member_Id
  where p.[Marital Status] = 1 and (GETDATE() - c.Birthday) > 10`

Edit 2. Sample Data
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vmWG.png)

Edit 3. The goal is to only see the single parents with Children under the age of 10. So in this the only records that should display should be Kim & Thomas

Comment: I just read the Title . . .I'm going to go shoot myself lol.

Comment: When you say _doesn't work`, what do you mean? It returns no rows?

Comment: Why not use datediff() ?    ...and  datediff(YEAR,c.Birthday,GetDate()) > 10

Comment: @Martin Apologies, I should have been clear, all I'm getting back is duplicates of the  other parent names and not the parents I'm looking for.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I tried that but it returns more duplicates as well. I only have 18 members but it returns up to 40+ with obvious duplicates

Comment: Evolve - no one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) via the where clause. And that's why you get so many rows - virtually a cross join.

Comment: @SMor I'm not sure what you mean, ie what?

Comment: @SMor Well done!  I missed that completely.   from Members p, Children c

Comment: You are doing a cross join over the tables, so you get the cartesian product as result.

Comment: I commented out the innerjoin so I can test if the age check works. I had to use the children table for this so I brought it in. In the full query it is removed.

Comment: If you just want to test the age check then you don't need the members table for that. You're seeing duplicates because you've used the wrong type of join.

Comment: If you're saying the real query is different and is still producing duplicates then a) show the real query and b) provide some sample source data, and the result you want from your query based on the that result. Then we can understand exactly what you're talking about

Comment: The question is this, What Logic would you use to determine how many single parents there are with Children under the age of 10? I need to use the members table to check

Comment: P.s. interesting data structure in the modern world ...how do you record children who have, shall we say, non-traditional caring/parental relationships? :-)

Comment: Like I said, show sample data and expected result and it'll be easier to help you with that. But my first point was that you don't need the members table to test the age function specifically

Comment: Also please use the "edit" button under your question to add extra info, don't post code or data in the comments, thanks.

Comment: @ADyson I edited the Question, as per your suggestion.  I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you single members:

```
select * from dbo.Members m
where m.[Marital Status] = 1
```

This gives you children under 10:

```
select * from dbo.Children c
where DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), c.Birthday) < 10
```

Now you need to put those together and it looks like it's by either Member_Id=Father_Id or Member_Id=Mother_Id, I'd use COALESCE() just to keep it simple:

```
select m.* from dbo.Members m
inner join dbo.Children c on COALESCE(c.Father_Id, c.Mother_Id) = m.Member_Id
where m.[Marital Status] = 1
and DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), c.Birthday) < 10
```

You could also just look at children with either a NULL Mother_Id or NULL Father_Id as that seems to indicate a child with 1 parent and not the other.

```
select * from dbo.Children c
where (c.Mother_Id is null or c.Father_Id is null)
and DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), c.Birthday) < 10
```

Comment: This did it, Thank you ever so much!

Comment: @Clutch you're welcome.  I'd  also suggest a possible redesign if you have control of that.   Where everyone in your church database is considered a member and you associate each member with each other via a Family_Id.  Then within that association you can say parent, child, etc...  Either way, glad I could help .

Answer (score 1):

You should use `< 10` instead of `> 10`:

```
select distinct p.[First Name]
from Members p
  inner join Children c on c.Father_Id = p.Member_Id
  or c.Mother_Id = p.Member_Id
  where p.[Marital Status] = 1 and (GETDATE() - c.Birthday) < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Date diff function.

```
   select distinct p.[First Name]
    from Members p
    inner join Children c on c.Father_Id = p.Member_Id
    or c.Mother_Id = p.Member_Id
     where p.[Marital Status] = 1 and DATEDIFF(year, c.Birthday, GETDATE()) > 10
```

Comment: this unfortunately does not work when you remove the inner join, you see my concern is that I should be able to filter by marital status and the date of birth without checking the parents link. So I'm trying to accomplish the same result by ensuring both parts work

Comment: @Clutch you're checking the marital status, which is associated with the parent(members) and you're checking the birth date of the child, you have to have the link between your members and children if that is your criteria.